# Is there a way to make a custom class that can have [] used on it in Java, similar to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, accessor

With Java, is there a way to make a custom class that can have the [] accessor used on it like an array?

Normal array

```
int[] foo = int[5];
foo[4] = 5;
print(foo[4]);
//Output: "5"
```

Custom Class

```
class Bar {
    //Custom class that uses index as a ref
}

Bar foo = new Bar(5);
foo.set(4, 5);
print(foo[4]);
//Output: "5"
```

Comment: I wish... If it were possible to override `[]`, we wouldn't be stuck with the ugly `list.get(5)` and `str.charAt(6)`?..

Comment: No, I keep hearing rumors that operator overloading will be in a later release of Java, however I honestly don't think it will be.

Comment: As a side note, look into groovy :)

Comment: @JonTaylor Honestly, I think Java has missed the bus on operator overloading.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not sure whether I want it to be in Java or not.  I like it, but then I also see a lot of mistakes with it.  Then again, I've always been one for wanting multiple inheritence in Java, one of the few it seems.

Comment: My impression has always been that Java deliberately didn't want operator overloading to be possible...and I think it makes sense.  (I have heard indications that it _might_ be baked in for the collection types, but for nothing else, which I'd be okay with.)

Comment: Great question, alas Java does not support this. It had been discussed as part of Java 7’s Project Coin but did not make it into the final version. Apparently, Java’s too conservative to use sexy syntax :)

Comment: @JonTaylor All the JCP proposals I've seen for operator overloading have involved in it being baked in for certain types and not user customisable - on things like BigInteger and BigDecimal for instance. There hasn't been any serious discussion that I'm aware of for it being made available as an extensible part of the language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you cannot overload `[]` operator for your classes in `Java`. But you can create getter for your array.

Answer (score 7):

No, Java doesn't have any operator overloading.

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll have to implement your `public <Type> get(int index){ ... }` method, like `ArrayList` does for example.

Answer (score 1):

No, to do this Java would have to add operator overloading of `[` and `]` - you need to use the equivalent get / set methods instead.

There's no current plans that I know of to implement operator overloading for any future version of Java - it's definitely not in the plan for Java 8, and the talks Oracle have given on Java 9 and beyond don't include plans for it either. Personally I'm not a fan of it - it introduces lots of complications such as precedence and order that can lead to subtle, annoying bugs unless users are incredibly careful, and (whether you agree with this stance or not) I believe this was the reason the decision was made to exclude it from the language in the first place.

Comment: General operator overloading does have some problems, but most of them stem from the fact that it's not inherently clear whether `thing1 + thing2` should be defined in thing1 or thing2.  By contrast, it's much more clear that `thing1[thing2]` should be defined in `thing1`.

Answer (score -4):

## Sure,

try

```
Bar[] foo = new Bar[4];
foo[2] = new Bar();
System.out.print(foo[2]);
```

Regards

Comment: Seriously, what is wrong? I cant imagine any sitouation the overloading of [] should be more favored than the inheritance of `Collection`. For every other cases: Make a array of `Bar`!